Unable to log traces in Mlflow
Here is my setup :

Mlflow 2.18.0
The server is deployed on AWS ECS
Using S3 for storing artifacts and AWS RDS for metadata

Here is a simple code for tracing, I'm using Mlflow decorator to trace a function
import mlflow

mlflow.set_tracking_uri("abc")
mlflow.set_experiment("xyz")

@mlflow.trace(name="Trace Test")
def trace_test(x):
    return x+1

trace_test(4)


Here is the error I'm getting -
WARNING mlflow.tracing.export.mlflow: Failed to log trace spans as tag to MLflow backend. Error: INTERNAL_ERROR: no Route matched with those values.

WARNING mlflow.tracing.export.mlflow: Failed to log trace to MLflow backend. Error: INTERNAL_ERROR: no Route matched with those values. For full traceback, set logging level to debug.

I can't find anything related to this error on Google, also I tried logging level to Debug but didn't get more information on these errors.
Other information : I can succesfully log models, runs but having problem with tracing feature.
